# Swift: Firestore sub collections, custom objects and listeners

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore

I have a model pattern as depicted in the below picture.

[image: Model]

In the UI I am trying to get all the `Countries` and related data. I have created respective structures and my idea was to use the custom object approach shown in the link [Custom_Objects](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#custom_objects). Now the problem I have is that `subcollections` won't come in the `querysnapshot` ( I am getting only the fields) and hence I cannot do the direct object mapping (as I have to query and retrieve the subcollections to make the object complete). for example: `Country` structure has `States` as one of the properties and without states `Country` object cannot be created and `States` further has provinces. Right now I am doing recursive looping to construct the whole structure which I am not feeling quite good.

So my question would be, what is the best way to handle this kind of data (provided there is no room for normalization and we can't avoid subcollections)?

Also if I want to get notified on any changes to State, Province or Town, do I need to separately add listeners to each collection or adding to the root is enough?

Here is the current code snap

```
    db.collection("countries").getDocuments { (QuerySnapshot, error) in
    if let error = error {
        print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
    }else{
        var docCount = QuerySnapshot!.documents.count
        for document in QuerySnapshot!.documents {
            self.fetchStatesForDoc(document: document, completion: { (nodes) in
                var data = document.data()
                data["states"] = nodes
                let country = Country(dictionary: data)
                self.countryList.append(country!)
                print(self.sectionList)
                docCount = docCount - 1
                if docCount == 0{
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.countryCollection.reloadData()
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
}
func fetchStatesForDoc(document: DocumentSnapshot, completion:@escaping ([State])-> Void){

    var states = [State]()
    document.reference.collection("states").getDocuments(completion: { (QuerySnapshot, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
        }else{
            var docCount = QuerySnapshot!.documents.count
            for document in QuerySnapshot!.documents {
                //print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())")
                var data = document.data()
                self.fetchProvincesForDoc(document: document, completion: { (provinces) in
                    data["Provinces"] = provinces
                    let state = State(dictionary: data)
                    states.append(state!)
                    docCount = docCount - 1
                    if docCount == 0{
                        completion(state)
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    })
}
func fetchProvincesForDoc(document: DocumentSnapshot, completion:@escaping ([Province])-> Void){

    var provinces = [Province]()
    document.reference.collection("provinces").getDocuments(completion: { (QuerySnapshot, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
        }else{
            var docCount = QuerySnapshot!.documents.count
            for document in QuerySnapshot!.documents {
                //print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())")
                var data = document.data()
                self.fetchTownsForDoc(document: document, completion: { (towns) in
                    data["towns"] = provinces
                    let province = Province(dictionary: data)
                    provinces.append(province!)
                    docCount = docCount - 1
                    if docCount == 0{
                        completion(province)
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    })
}
func fetchTownssForDoc(document: DocumentSnapshot, completion:@escaping ([Towns])-> Void) {

    var towns = [Towns]()
    document.reference.collection("towns").getDocuments(completion: { (QuerySnapshot, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
        }else{
            for document in QuerySnapshot!.documents {
                //print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())")
            }
            towns = QuerySnapshot!.documents.compactMap({Towns(dictionary: $0.data())})
            completion(towns)
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> Now the problem I have is that subcollections wont come in the querysnapshot ( I am getting only the fields)

That's right, this is how Cloud Firestore queries works. The queries are named shallow, which means they only get items from the collection that the query is run against. There is no way to get documents from a top-level collection and a subcollections in a single query. Firestore doesn't support queries across different collections in one go. A single query may only use properties of documents in a single collection. That's why ypu cannot see the subcollection in the `querysnapshot` object so you can do the direct object mapping.

> what is the best way to handle these kind of data (provided there is no room for normalization and we cant avoid subcollections)?

In this case you should query the database twice, once to get the objects within the collection and second to get all the objects within the subcollection.

There is also another practice which is called denormalization and is a common practice when it comes to Firebase. This technique implies also querying the database twice. If you are new to NoQSL databases, I recommend you see this video, [Denormalization is normal with the Firebase Database](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vKqXSZLLnHA) for a better understanding. It is for Firebase realtime database but same rules apply to Cloud Firestore.

Also, when you are duplicating data, there is one thing that need to keep in mind. In the same way you are adding data, you need to maintain it. With other words, if you want to update/detele an item, you need to do it in every place that it exists.

So in this case, you can denormalize your data by creating a top-level collection in which you should add all the objects that exist in your subcollections. It's up to you to decide which practice is better for you.

Comment: Thanks for the response.... with my current solution I am able to get the subcollections and stuffs and able to create the objects ....but I am doing a recursive loop for each collection from bottom to top ie towns --> provinces --> states--> Countries...once the loop gets over you will get a list of countries and childs filled... but I am not sure if this is the best way

Comment: As long as you have separate queries for each individual collection/subcollection and you have the desired result, that's that way you should go ahead.

Comment: Then comes the listener.. how to listen to changes to these kind of data?

Comment: If you want to listen to realtime updates, then you should use [addSnapshotListener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen).

Comment: Yeah I know but add that to each document? Can I add a listener to a root collection and notified if anything under its tree is changed?

Comment: No, this is happening only in Firebase realtime database where you can add a listener on a particular node and get all subnodes updates. Unfortunately, this is not possible in Cloud Firestore.

Comment: If you want to listen to changes you should use nested quries. In this way you can get the data, once the first one is completed.